# Pausing a timer in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, timer, sprite-kit

Hey guys self teaching newbie here. So I'm trying to pause a game in SpriteKit and while the pause somewhat works it isn't pausing my timer. Now I know you can't use NSTimer in SpriteKit because it doesn't play well with the paused state so I used the `SKScene update:` method and use the passed-in currentTime parameter to keep track of time. But, when I pause my game, the timer doesn't pause. Anyone out there with work around for this? Below is the code for the timer and the pause.

```
-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    if (self.startGame){
        self.startTime = currentTime;
        self.startGame = NO;
    }
int countDownInt = 10.0 - (int)(currentTime - self.startTime);

if (self.gameStartTimer) {
    if (countDownInt>0){
        self.timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countDownInt];
    }else if (countDownInt == 0) {
        self.timerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"TIME"];
        LoseConditionScene *loseScene = [LoseConditionScene sceneWithSize:self.frame.size];
        SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:1.0];
        [self.view presentScene:loseScene transition:transition];
    }
}
```

}

```
-(void)pauseGame {
    _isGamePaused = YES; //Set pause flag to true
    self.scene.view.paused = YES; //Pause scene and physics simulation

-(void)unpauseGame {
    _isGamePaused = NO; //Set pause flag to false
    self.scene.view.paused = NO;

-(void)registerAppTransitionObservers
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationWillResignActive) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:NULL];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackground) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:NULL];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationWillEnterForeground) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:NULL];

}

-(void)applicationWillResignActive
{
    if (_isGamePaused) { //Pause the game is necessary
        [self pauseGame];
    }
}
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground
{
    self.scene.view.paused = YES;
}

-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground
{
    self.scene.view.paused = NO; //Unpause the SKView
    if (_isGamePaused) {
        self.paused = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: update: doesn't pause unless the SKView is paused if I remember correctly and in case this might be the problem

Comment: I suggest you create a countdown timer with an SKAction instead of creating one in update.

Comment: ^Any suggestions on where I can go to learn how to do that?

Comment: Also, I need this timer to be visible in game so making it an SKAction isn't an option.